# Union of DataSets in ApacheFlink

Tags: scala, bigdata, apache-flink

I'm trying to union a `Seq[DataSet(Long,Long,Double)]` to 
a single `DataSet[(Long,Long,Double)]` in Flink:

```
     val neighbors= graph.map(el => zKnn.neighbors(results,
      el.vector, 150, metric)).reduce(
     (a, b) => a.union(b)
      ).collect()
```

Where graph is a regular scala collections but can be converted to DataSet;
results is a `DataSet[Vector]` and should not be collected and is needed in the neighbors method

I always get a FlinkRuntime Exeption:

> cannot currently handle nodes with more than 64 outputs.
>         org.apache.flink.optimizer.CompilerException: Cannot currently handle nodes with more than 64 outputs.
>       at org.apache.flink.optimizer.dag.OptimizerNode.addOutgoingConnection(OptimizerNode.java:347)
>       at org.apache.flink.optimizer.dag.SingleInputNode.setInput(SingleInputNode.java:202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink does not support union operators with more than 64 input data sets at the moment.

As a workaround you can hierarchically union up to 64 data sets and inject an identity mapper between levels of the hierarchy.
Something like:

```
DataSet level1a = data1.union(data2.union(data3...(data64))).map(new IDMapper());
DataSet level1b = data65.union(data66...(data128))).map(new IDMapper());
DataSet level2 = level1a.union(level1b)
```

Comment: Does Flink 1.16 support more than 64 now?